# How to get apostille at the U.S. State Department for FBI background check?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, spain, student-visas

I am in the process of applying for Spanish student visa, and I need it "legalized with the Apostille of the Hague Convention by the Department of State in Washington DC."

I have already received the PDF of the FBI background check. According to some guides, I just need to send "the FBI background check results (the printout of the PDF), Form DS-4194, payment, and return mailing envelope" to the Office of Authentication [(source)](https://www.middlebury.edu/schools-abroad/schools/spain/student-visa/spain-student-visa-instructions). However, the state department website says the document must be notarized and certified before sending in. ([source](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/apostille-requirements.html))

So should I get the background check notarized and certified, or should I just send in the PDF printout?

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from Reddit (@givemegreencard), thought I'd share.

> I sent just a printout of the PDF in. The apostille is the US
> government attesting to the signature of the person signing the
> document.
>
> For something that is not a government document, such as a contract,
> you need a notary (technically a government official) to sign your
> document. Then the Department of State of the state that appoints the
> notary (i.e. the State of California) issues an apostille.
>
> If you need to apostille a birth certificate issued by a state, same
> thing -- you go to that state's Department of State to get an
> apostille to authenticate the signature of the state health official
> on the birth certificate.
>
> In this case, you have the signature of a federal government official,
> someone in the FBI. So the federal Department of State must apostille
> it, and because it's the signature of a government official already,
> you don't go and get it notarized again.